# An experiment for to calculate the range of a projectile

Tags: experimental-physics, home-experiment

The range $R$ of a projectile is the horizontal distance the projectile travels before of touchdown. We know that,

$$R=\dfrac{2v_0^2}{g}\sin\theta\cos\theta \tag{1}$$

If I wanted to do a realistic experiment in a field in front of my school for my students and I have not the sensors that measure the range angle $\theta$ of a kicked ball and the initial speed $v_0$, what could be the alternative solutions to do the experiment to find $R$?

Comment: What would be the *objective* of the experiment?

Comment: @Gert Hi, to find $R$. Now I edit the question.

Comment: Hmmm .. your equation (1) is a "in the absence of drag" realtionship, which means you need to stick to realtively slow speeds and dense enough projectiles. A few meters per second peak speeds and high-density plastics gave pretty good results for my students in a slightly different context. But one of the harder parts of range experiments is getting reliably launch conditions.

Comment: You can use Gert's approach to verify the range equation.  Note - the range equation is only good if you land at the launch height.

Comment: @dmckee I've got a student of mine playing soccer. I could use a light plastic ball if he or someone else has it. Unfortunately, physics experiments on parabolic motion cannot be performed due to both technical difficulties ( absence of any instruments) and operative calculation procedures of my students. They want to go to the laboratory because they have never been there: but my question is, will they remember the basic elements of error theory? Do they know how to work with indirect measurements and find the relative errors?

Comment: I had my students using a small plastic balls, a white/blackboard, and a cellphone camera to do a general parabolic motion type experiment. They used a meter-stick and plumb-bob and level to draw a grid on the board, and filmed the action while they threw the ball in front of the grid. Find step-wise velocity componenets and graph those as a function of time. Slopes give accceleration componenets and they can compare to the expectation. But they found the analysis confusing and error propogation just made it worse.

Comment: @dmckee I really appreciate the advice, especially from people as polite and respectful as you. What do you advise me to do? Forget it or will I make the experiment run the same?

Comment: Until you have tried it out you won't know how well it will work (but you can run it yourself to find out if it is feasible). And you won't know how the students handle the analysis until you let *them* try it. I could send you the lab instructions I use for that ball-tossing lab after I get home tonight if you would like them. They have at least been used a few times. Are you OK with me peeking at the email address you used to sign up for the site with my moderator super-powers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual  $R$ can be determined by direct measurement, much like the length of a Javelin throw is determined.

The angle of launch $\theta$ could be determined from a well-timed photo of the launch, using a smart phone e.g.

The launch velocity $v_0$ could be determined from the flight time. The horizontal and vertical components of the flight are independent (*in the absence of drag, see @dmckee's comment*) of each other.

The vertical initial launch velocity $v_{y,i}$ is given by:

$$v_{y,i}=v_0\sin\theta$$

After launch at $t=0$, the object decelerates by $g$ until its velocity is $0$ at the apex:

$$v_0\sin\theta-g\Delta t=0$$

where $\Delta t$ is the time to reach the apex. The time needed to descend back to Earth is the same, so the total flight time is:

$$\Delta t_{tot}=2\Delta t$$

Assuming the angle $\theta$ is known, $v_0$ can be extracted from $\Delta t_{tot}$.

Needless to say, there's plenty of room for things to go wrong, from too large measuring errors to actual errors so you need to plan carefully and repeat often.